NextJS Route Handler: log uncaught exceptions & rejected promises to Winston
I'm using the App Router from NextJS >13. Trying to figure out how to automatically log all uncaught errors in API route handlers to Winston. I tried process.on("uncaughtException", ...) and process.on("unhandledRejection", ...) but these events don't seem to be generated by errors inside a POST method in a route.ts file.
